# Sequelize Association throws an error in Create

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do a simple association with sequelize in my NodeJS API, the idea is simple, I  want to create a person and his type in the same moment. I try to follow the docs, but, when the create function is called Sequelize throws the error

**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined"**

Bellow is the code used:

Models 

Person.js

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize) => {
  const Person = sequelize.define('person', {
    email: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    nickname: { type: Sequelize.STRING(60) },
    fullname: { type: Sequelize.STRING(60) },
    observation: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
  }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true });

  Person.associate = (models) => {
    Person.hasOne(models.PersonType, {
      foreignKey: 'person_id',
    });
  };

  return Person;
};
```

PersonType.js

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const PersonType = sequelize.define('person_type', {
    type: { type: Sequelize.STRING(14), unique: true },
  }, { underscored: true, freezeTableName: true });

  PersonType.associate = (models) => {
    PersonType.belongsTo(models.Person, {
      foreignKey: 'person_id',
    });
  };

  return PersonType;
};
```

index.js

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import console from 'console';

const database = process.env.DB_URL;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  underscored: true,
});

const models = {
   Person: sequelize.import('./person'),
   PersonType: sequelize.import('./personType'),
};

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});

models.sequelize = sequelize;
models.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default models;
```

The file where I try to execute the operation:

```
import models from '../models';

export default class PersonOperations {
  constructor(db) {
    this.db = db; // db here is the sequelize model of Person
  }

  create(person) {
    return this.db.create({
      email: person.email,
      nickname: person.nickname,
      observation: person.observation,
      personType: {
        type: person.personType.type,
      },
    }, {
      include: [{
        model: models.PersonType,
        include: [person.personType],
      }],
    });
  }
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (/home/~/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:465:30)
    at options.include.options.include.map.include (/home/~/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:395:37)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function._validateIncludedElements (/home/~/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:390:39)
```

I have already tried a lot of different things that I have found, but none of them helped me.

- I am using freezeTableName, I have already tried to remove that, drop the database and create again, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Just Comment out the below code block from `Person.js` and run the code

```
Person.associate = (models) => {
    Person.hasOne(models.PersonType, {
      foreignKey: 'person_id',
    });
};
```

> **Reason of error :**
>
> Here you are creating the circular dependecies ,  using
>   `models.PersonType` inside `models.Person` and then after using
>   `models.Person` inside `models.PersonType`

`hasOne` and `belongsTo` both are the same thing only diff is (**[READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto)**) :

```
Player.belongsTo(Team)  // `teamId` will be added on Player / Source model
Coach.hasOne(Team)  // `coachId` will be added on Team / Target model
```

Comment: Hey @Vivek Doshi, thank you very much for your answer, It really help me. After the change I got: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: person_type is not associated to person! Any ideia?

Comment: Try to comment out that code from persontype model and keep it in person model and then try again

Comment: Hey Vivek Doshi, I did that but still can't store the data in the correct way. If I leave on the code, inside the include, just the model, It save the person, but not the person type. If I let the second include, I still get the table name error.